# Change li class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dom, addclass

I want to change the class of the current li(list) which is selected

```
 $('li.doBlokkeer').click(function(e) {
 $(this).addClass('doDEBlokkeer').removeClass('doBlokkeer');
 });

 $('li.doDEBlokkeer').click(function(e) {
 $(this).addClass('doBlokkeer').removeClass('doDEBlokkeer');
 });
```

so if a current li is selected its class need to be changed (it needs to have doDEBlokkeer). The above code works..
The problem is that this only works once for each LI item..

when I click on li.doBlokkeer the class changes which is good, but when I press the same current li again, it calls the same function li.doBlokkeer instead of li.doDEBlokkeer function (despite the css class) . I tried so much stuff but i really can't find any solution. can you guys help me out? I have been searching for a solution for more then 14 hours, so frustrated right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that you are binding the event on the class selector (for the element existed in DOM at that time ) which gets changed dynamically so your binding is lost. You can consider using event delegation syntax or bind it to a different class/selector which doesn't change.

Using Event delegation (jq >=1.7) you can try:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li.doBlokkeer', function(e) {
     $(this).addClass('doDEBlokkeer').removeClass('doBlokkeer');
 });

 $('ul').on('click', 'li.doDEBlokkeer', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('doBlokkeer').removeClass('doDEBlokkeer');
 });
```

Another shortcut:

```
$('.cls').click(function (e) { // add a common class to all lis and bind the click event to that.
    var flg = $(this).is('.doBlokkeer'); //check if it is a specific class
    $(this).addClass(function () {
        return flg ? 'doDEBlokkeer' : 'doBlokkeer'; //based on flag return the other class
    }).removeClass(function () {
        return flg ? 'doBlokkeer' : 'doDEBlokkeer'; //based on flag return the other class
    });
});
```

or just:

```
$('.cls').click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('doDEBlokkeer').toggleClass('doBlokkeer');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur4qn/)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/622mV/)**

Comment: Also jquery's toggleClass is an alternative to add/remove class. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: @ThaddeusAlbers very good point. i forgot abt that... :) It makes it just one line..

Comment: Using `toggleClass` will produce an unwanted result if the element starts off WITHOUT either `doDEBlokkeer` or `doBlokkeer` classes.

Comment: @Marcel it is highly unlikely here looking at what OP is trying to achieve. he might have a class already set since he is binding event to them.

Comment: PSL omg you really made my day.. This works like a charm!! thank you so much for the explanation

Comment: Yes, true, but in the broadest of terms, it may cause someone more headaches ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, please consider this:

```
$('li').click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        one = 'doBlokkeer',
        two = 'doDEBlokkeer';

    if ( $this.hasClass(one) ) {
        $this.removeClass(one).addClass(two);
    } else {
        $this.removeClass(two).addClass(one);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('li.doBlokkeer').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('doDEBlokkeer');
});
```

There is no need for the second click event

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as explained earlier, that you bind the event to an element with the given class name, then, on click you change the class name, so the handler doesn't listen to it any more...

I would recommend to stick with event delegation because it's lighter and you can also nest elements in your `li`s (like a link or a div etc.):
First add the class `'cls'`to your `<ul>`, so `<ul class="cls">`. Your HTML could the look like:

```
<ul class="cls">
    <li class="doBlokkeer"><div>Click on me</div></li>
    <li class="doDEBlokkeer">Click on me</li>
    <li class="doBlokkeer">Click on me</li>
    <li class="doBlokkeer">Click on me</li>
</ul>
```

All you need for your javaScript is now:

```
$('.cls').on('click', '.doDEBlokkeer, .doBlokkeer', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('doDEBlokkeer doBlokkeer');
});
```

...which requires jQuery 1.7. If you have only jQuery 1.4.2 and up you can use '.delegate()`

```
$('.cls').delegate('.doDEBlokkeer, .doBlokkeer', 'click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('doDEBlokkeer doBlokkeer');
});
```

The event (and only one) is now on the `ul` and the `.on()` pickes out the right elements defined by the class names you passed through.

I updated the [fiddle from PSL](http://jsfiddle.net/622mV/3/)